# How do I create a mutually-incompatible type library in Java?

Tags: java, design, object-oriented, generics

Folks, this seems like it should be straightforward, but I'm drawing a blank here.

As a simplified example, consider an abstract class called Number with an abstract method add(). I want to create two concrete subclasses, Integer and Float, with method signatures Integer.add(Integer other) and Float.add(Float  other). A Float can NOT be added to an Integer. What should the method signature of the abstract add() method in the Number class be in order to enforce this constraint at compile-time?

Comment: generics: `interface Num<T>{ T add(T); }`

Comment: I honestly do not think Java is the right language to be doing this sort of thing in

Comment: I did end up using jozefg's solution... I have `interface Number<T extends Number<T>>{ T add(T other); }` 
And then with Float as `class Float implements Number<Float>` etc. The aim was ease of use for my library consumers, so while aviv's answer makes perfect sense, this is an example where usability trumps correctness. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 4):

`Number` should not have an `add()` method.

Declaring a method in a base class (Or in an interface, for that matter), is a promise to implement this method. If your base class has `add(Integer i)`, that's a promise that each instance of `Number` - be it a `Float` or an `Integer` - will have that method.

You can use generics, as jozefg commented - but then your two classes **do not share a common superclass**: `Integer extends Number<Integer>`, and `Float extends Number<Float>`. These are two different classes, that share their code. At runtime (In Java), erasure makes it look like it's the same class, but that's a technicality; When it comes to static  (compile-time) terms, the two classes are distinct.

Another dynamic solution is to have `Number` define either `add(Number)`, or both `add(Integer)` and `add(Float)`, and throw an exception when the wrong method is invoked; This is certainly not what you're after, and is not generally considered a good use of Object-Oriented features.

Comment: My background is C#, but if you really need them to share the same superclass, couldn't you have `Number<T> extends Number` and have a separate `Number` base with anything that can be untyped in there?

Comment: You could (almost), but the base `Number` would not have the `add()` method. The middle-level, `Number<T>` would be two different (compile-time, and in C#, runtime too) classes.
(Almost: In java, they can't both be named Number, because of the way generics are implemented).